# How to create a numpy array of arrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

The following code creates two arrays, A and B.
A is actually a numpy array of arrays, only because its subarrays don't have the same length.

```
arr1 = np.arange(2,7)
arr2 = np.arange(5,7)
arr3 = np.arange(7,9)
A = np.array([arr1, arr2, arr3])


arr1 = np.arange(2,4)
arr2 = np.arange(5,7)
arr3 = np.arange(7,9)
B = np.array([arr1, arr2, arr3])
```

Now, my question is how to force B also to be an array of arrays even if its subarrays have the same length?

Comment: The surest way of making an object dtype array, is to initialize it as such, eg. `np.empty(3, dtype=object)` (which will be filled with `None`), and assign the individual arrays to it.  `arr[:] = [arr1, arr2, arr3]` might work (if broadcasting doesn't get in the way).

Comment: I think you have your `A` and `B` switched.  `B` is the standard 2D array, and `A` is an array or arrays in your example

Comment: Thanks, James! Corrected.

Comment: @hpaulj. How could broadcasting screw things up? (It doesn't in this case at least)

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I agree that in this case it doesn't  May be it's more of a vague memory of problems in the past.  `B[:]=np.ones((3,2))` has problems.  `B[:]=list(np.ones((3,2)))` does not.